# Why is msg.d not supported in Mono 2.6.1?

Tags: json, mono, webmethod

Currently I have webservice running on the Mono platform.  When I call the service I get the data in the form of msg, and not msg.d.  Any thoughts?

Update:

Wow, this turns out to be a big deal.  As [Phil Haack explains](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx), this opens up the possibility of an XSS attack when you use a GET to fetch the data.  Question still stands:  should this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said `Justin` on `mono-aspnet-list@lists.ximian.com`:

> This is a bug.  It has been fixed in 2.6 svn and in the trunk.

http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-aspnet-list/2010-March/000663.html